# Sub-domain as sub-directory in URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We need solution for our new server, we have one main domain e.g. example.com and its hosted on VPS this website is in ASP.Net with blog e.g. example.com/blog , The blog is in sub-directory and using Wordpress. We got new server and we want to move our blog on new VPS so we created sub-domain on main domain e.g. blog.example.com and change the A Record in control panel and blog.example.com is working fine, but we want to show URL like this example.com/blog/ is there a any way we can show sub-domain as a sub-directory ? The main website will remain host on main server we only need to work with sub-domain. So it shows all links like, example.com/blog/post-name/

Comment: A "reverse proxy" is what you're looking for. It can be as easy as a RewriteRule if you're using apache and have mod_rewrite and mod_proxy enabled, or you could do it in nginx, if you're using it as a front end.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed the WHM and check the apache module of mod_rewrite but I could not find it. However I find the mod_proxy which is enable. How can I activate the mod_rewrite? via .htaccess?

Comment: It's very unlikely that mod_rewrite isn't enabled. Does it crash if you add `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess? If it does, you'll need to enable it, which can be as simple as running `a2enmod rewrite` as root and restarting apache. If that works, try the [P-flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

Comment: I enabled it, perhaps it was enabled already, but if you share any article where I can learn about the reverse proxy in WHM would be awesome. Actually I just need solution for to make the URL from blog.example.com from example.com/blog while main domain example.com remains on main server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://blog.example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

It uses mod_proxy (and will fail if it's not available) to reverse proxy the traffic beneath /blog/. Obviously, if you have a lot of traffic or bad connection between the two servers, you will want something that does cache, but usually works quite good.

You will probably have to set

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/blog');
```

in your wp-config.php so the internal links point to the URL you want them to work as.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried with above method, but I got 404 Not Found error. And mod_proxy is enabled.

Comment: That's strange, it works fine on multiple servers for me. Do you see the requests on the target server? 404s usually point to mod_proxy not being available. Did you put this above the WP rules? Otherwise WP will take over and present your 404.

Comment: I put top code in .htaccess and define('WP_HOME' code in wp-config.php file. The URL show example.com/blog but with 404 error. Do I have to do something on other server where my main domain example.com is hosted or everything on blog.example.com server?

Comment: The .htaccess stuff goes on your main domain, only the `define` statements go into the wp-config.php of your blog-server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I put the code on main server and on blog server I put code on wp-config.php, now example.com/blog is working fine, few pages like login is working but posts and pages links example.com/blog/post-name is not working, return with 404 page. Thanks :)

Comment: I change the permalinks to just show the post name without the year and month now the error is "Internal Server Error".

Comment: Look at the error log for the Internal Server Error. Might be a redirect loop, or a real configuration error somewhere.

Comment: [Tue Nov 14 11:38:14.546130 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21777] [client 103.255.7.41:30453] /home/blogshowdemo/public_html/.htaccess: ProxyPass not allowed here
[Tue Nov 14 11:38:14.545934 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21777] [client 103.255.7.41:30453] /home/blogshowdemo/public_html/.htaccess: ProxyPass not allowed here
[Tue Nov 14 11:38:13.357440 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21776] [client 103.255.7.41:30452] /home/blogshowdemo/public_html/.htaccess:

Comment: But on errors on main server, and these errors are not recent, they time of errors was 11:38 and now 2:40 AM.

Comment: Mhh. Does the 500 Internal Server Error show up in the access log (on both servers, or just on the main server?), or is it a browser error?

Comment: Errors are not showing in main server and in blog server the old errors are showing not the 500 Internal Server Error. I think it only show on browser.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: blog.showdemo.info and main domain is http://showdemo.info.

The main domain registered with Godaddy and hosted on NameCheap.com and for blog.showdemo.info Im using different server.

Comment: That seems to be a problem on the blog-server, as it'll also happen when you directly call [a post](http://blog.showdemo.info/dummy-post/) on it. You'll have to look into the php.ini, display_errors, error_reporting etc pp. Just switch on everything, make error_reporting = E_ALL, and see what happens.

Comment: I have checked all the errors in cPanel, did not see any new error or related to current error, also I don't have any PHP.INI file in file manager too.

Comment: I rename the .htaccess file on blog server and now error is 404 not found, it means we have issue with .htaccess file? and in file I have this code:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: It might, bot not necessarily. Without the .htaccess, the request doesn't get to WP, so WP has no chance to fail and return the error. If the .htaccess itself was bad directly,it should already fail for the request to /blog/, as it would be interpreted for that one as well. Please try with  [WP_DEBUG & Co](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG). And php.ini should be either configure through cPanel or edited via SSH (probably /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, or 7 instead of 5, the name is shown when you run phpinfo() in a file).

Comment: Hello, I used WP_DEBUG, add the php.ini file to show errors logs, I can see the file error_log but not anything in it, I try almost everything but nothing is working, I cannot even the permalinks. Any idea what it could be.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it's in WP, so it should show up in apache's error log if PHP is configured correctly. I've never used cPanel, so I don't know where that would be set up, or where that log file would be stored.

Comment: Hello, The issue was in .htaccess file, 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress